# Entity Framework Fluent Configurations In DomainClasses Layer or DataAccess Layer?

Tags: entity-framework

Entity Framework Fluent Configurations (which inherite from EntityTypeConfiguration<> or ComplexTypeConfiguration<>) for mapping entities to database,must be include in DomainClasses Layer or DataAccess Layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a purpose of the mapping? To describe how are entities persisted in the database and what layer is responsible for persistence and database dependencies? Data access layer.